# Proving that if $s_1$ and $s_2$ are eigenvalues for a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$, then the columns of $A-Is_1$ is a eigenvector for $s_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I seem to have gotten stuck on what at first glance doesn't seem to be a difficult question,

I wish to prove that if $s_1$ and $s_2$ are eigenvalues for a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$, then the columns of $A-Is_1$ is a eigenvector for $s_2$

I think some property of the transpose of a matrix is involved but I'm not sure. If possible I would like suggestions on solving it both by getting in and focusing on the components of the matrix/vectors, and suggestions on solving the problem using more abstract properties.

Thanks

Comment: You have to be a bit careful in the case $s_1=s_2$. If $A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, then one of the columns of $A-1I$ is the zero vector (the other one is fine). Maybe it is assumed that $s_1\neq s_2$ or that your matrix is diagonalizable?

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's see: since $\;s_1,s_2\;$ are the matrix's eigenvalues, the characteristic polynomial is $\;(x-s_1)(x-s_2)=x^2-(s_1+s_2)x+s_1s_2\;$ , and then Cayley-Hamilton's  Theorems tells us

$$(*)\;\;A^2-(s_1+s_2)A+s_1s_2I=0\implies A\color{red}{(A-s_1I)}=A^2-s_1A\stackrel{(*)}=s_2A-s_2s_1I=$$

$$=s_2\color{red}{(A-s_1I)}$$

and we're done.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way of doing it without the Cayley-Hamilton theorem?

Comment: Perhaps writing down explicitly the matrix, doing its product by $\;A-s_1I\;$ explicitly and stuff. What's the problem with C-H? It's a rather basic theorem.

Answer (score 1):

let us take $A = \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}.$  then $s_1, s_2$ are roots of the quadratic equation $(s-a)(s-d) - bc = 0.$ we will need $$s_1 + s_2 = a + d, s_1s_2 = ad - bc.$$

let us compute

$\begin{align}(A - s_2I)\pmatrix{a-s_1\\c} &= 
\pmatrix{(a-s_2)(a-s_1) + bc\\a-s_1)c+(d-s_2)c} \\
&= \pmatrix{a^2 -(s_1+s_2)a + s_1s_2 + bc\\(a+d)c-(s_1+s_2)c}\\
&= \pmatrix{a^2 -(a+d)a + ad-bc + bc\\(a+d)c -(a+d)c}\\
&= \pmatrix{0\\0}.\\
\end{align}$

you can use the same idea to show $(A - s_2I)\pmatrix{b\\d-s_1} = \pmatrix{0\\0}. $

Comment: If one does not want to do the same calculation twice, one can simply argue that $A-s_1I$ is non-invertible, and hence its column vectors are parallel. It is thus sufficient to do the calculation you did.